# Convert BigQuery TableRow to GenericRecord in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

Is there any functionality in beam which can be used to convert bigquery tablerows to avro generic records?

I'm trying to find any reference for something similar but I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryUtils.html (TableRow -> Row)
and
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/utils/AvroUtils.html (Row -> GenericRecord)

You will still need a schema though.